# When is an academic a -sensei and when is he/she a -hakase?

Tags: etiquette, email, titles, japan

I'm not Japanese, and I've been emailed by someone who is Japanese, in the context of potential academic collaboration. He's in industry, not academia. He used the "-sensei" honorific to refer to me, while I had called him using his company-position-related honorific.

This seemed strange to me, since he's older and more senior than me (in most respects anyway). I was assuming he'd call me "-san", or if he wanted to be nice, then "-hakase" or no honorific at all.

My question: In what circumstances is it customary to call non-medical academics, with a doctoral degree, "-sensei", and in what circumstances is "-hakase" the custom?

Comment: Sensei is a general term for a teacher, especially a master teacher. A Zen Buddhist learns from a sensei unless the teacher has a specific high title such as a Roshi. In Chinese, a sensei would be sifu. Skilled at teaching. Specifically, it indicates respect of the student for the teacher.

Comment: Nothing hard and fast- sensei is a general respectful term for a teacher. -hakase I think specifically refers to doctorates, but is a little awkward because a fresh PhD and a senior would both be -hakase, so it puts them in the same bracket. Sensei is safe and common. I'm not Japanese though, would love to hear more nuance if someone can share.

Comment: @Buffy: I know that. I should mention my conversation partner is not a student, and our interaction will not be about me teaching him things (other than how we all learn from knowledgeable people blah blah).

Comment: I think your partner is saying they have learned something useful/interesting from you and so you are, to them, sensei. Whether you thought you were teaching or not. Or, possibly, the person has misinterpreted your title/position. The Japanese can be quite polite.

Comment: @Buffy: But I haven't told him anything yet :-P

Comment: And you don't need to be an academic at all to be sensei to me. Or even formally educated, I suspect.

Comment: @Buffy not sure about the way it works in Japanese culture, but your analogy to the Chinese sifu (“师父”/“师傅”) is not really accurate. No one would ever call their teacher in real life as that, unless maybe you were a Shaolin monk and referring to your teacher of martial arts. The usual phrase is *laoshi* 老师 or just *shi* 师, although "professor" would translate to *boshi* 博士 (note that this *shi* is different).

Comment: @YiFan, thanks. I take it from Tai Chi, actually. And neither monk, nor master.

Comment: Probably "hakase" is for pure researcher or scientists in research institutions, not academic institutions. While "sensei" for academicians in universities, medical doctors, teachers, instructors, sifu, ... But not sure if "hakase" is usually used to address people or not.

Comment: @kate: Why is an academic not a "pure researcher"? Or rather, are you speaking from knowledge of custom, or your common-sense assumption?

Comment: _I haven't told him anything yet_: A non-Japanese person might address you as _Professor_ before you tell them anything (regardless of whether you have that title), sensei is the equivalent

Comment: @einpoklum What I mean by "an academician is not a pure researcher" is because academicians do not only do research, but also teach; while research scientists at research institutes do not have the obligation to teach, their job is researching. From my limited observation though, so I might be wrong.

Answer (score 4):

I've lived in Japan for two years and can speak the language to some extent.

[Keigo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honorific_speech_in_Japanese) is *complicated*, and any rule you learn about seems to have lots of exceptions. After two years, I felt that I had *some* idea, but I felt that I had far from mastered the intricacies. In particular, older people often addressed me using keigo for reasons I didn't quite understand.

"Sensei" is a general respectful term for a teacher. Since he is interested in an *academic* collaboration specifically, perhaps he regards you as "senior" because you have an academic position and he does not.

"Sensei" is a general and common form of address, used for academics and other teachers. I have not heard "hakase" used as a form of address.

In any case, he has certainly addressed you with respect. If you're unsure of what Japanese title to use, and your correspondence is in English, I'd encourage addressing him in English as "Mr. X" or (if he has a doctorate) "Dr. X".